# How can I apply classes faster or simulatneously?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mobile-safari

I have an array of DOM-elements, it's like 5 of them

```
this.children = Array.from(wrapper.children)
```

At a given event, i loop through the elements and conditionally apply differenct classes:

```
this.children.forEach((child, i) => {
    let classes = child.classList;
    classes.toggle('flic-before', i < s+1);
    classes.toggle('flic-active', i === s);
    classes.toggle('flic-previous', i === s-1);
    classes.toggle('flic-next', i === s+1);
})
```

This works fine in all browsers because the javascript is fast enough for the css to not update. But in iPhone, the classes get applied to the first elements one frame before the other, this causes a flicker on the screen.

Is there some way for me to apply all elements at the same time or atleast do the application notably faster?

Comment: I don't think a micro-gain is worth compromising readability, and that's what it would take to do it all in 1

Comment: you could detach them, apply the changes, then reattach them. but... that'll likely cause a flicker too on the iphone.

Comment: Can you provide a demo that replicates the problem - a plunk, etc?

Answer (score 1):

[`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) function allows you to define code that MUST be executed at once, before next render. There is no chance to just optimize this code chunk - just because array length could change in future. This approach guarantees no flicker on the screen

Please wrap your code into [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) just like this:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    // Please NOTE that this code will be executed asynchronously
    this.children.forEach((child, i) => {
        let classes = child.classList;
        classes.toggle('flic-before', i < s+1);
        classes.toggle('flic-active', i === s);
        classes.toggle('flic-previous', i === s-1);
        classes.toggle('flic-next', i === s+1);
    });
});
```

This will guarantee that nothing at the middle of the update will be shown to user

---

PERFORMANCE

This async hook will be much faster than synchronous code in the flicker cases. Because browser won't spend time on the relayout and repaint(next frame display) which takes significant amount of time

(Also this code give the same performance in non-flicker cases, 99.9999999% sure)

---

PROOF

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvdZbN?editors=1111

Comment: I doesn't understand why it is voted down. You need to just wrap your code into `requestAnimationFrame` to make sure that noting at the middle of update procedure will be rendered and visible to people.

Comment: Most likely it was voted down because it's really just a link-only answer, which really should just be a comment.

Comment: I guess the problem here is that forEach loop takes too much time. Why is asynchronous hook supposed to be visibly faster than *synchronous* code? If this is the solution to this problem, some reliable information and/or a demo would be helpful.

Comment: @estus updated, added notes, comments, explained performance, etc. Anything else?

Comment: You're describing requestAnimationFrame like all repaint is paused until callback function is completed, even if it takes several seconds. I didn't witness that. Can you provide a reference that confirms this behaviour? TBH, I never witnessed the behaviour that OP describes too, the problem explained in the question sounds a bit unrealistic and obscure without a demo.

Comment: @estus Please look at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvdZbN?editors=1111 Also added to answer

Comment: That's a bit different. I'm positive that next requestAnimationFrame won't be called in this case until previous requestAnimationFrame  is completed because it's JS, and JS is executed in main thread. This doesn't necessarily mean that UI thread stalls at well. And I'd expect that it doesn't because this way main thread could introduce freezes to UI thread, this defies the purpose of having separate thread for smooth UI.

Comment: @estus Seems like you main mistake is that you think that UI thread doesn't render DOM changes until JS event loop is finished. It is not true

Comment: @estus not always true

Comment: This is not what I think, but I don't think I ever witnessed the opposite. I assume this may be engine-specific. Just saying that the example with a sequence of requestAnimationFrame calls doesn't add clarification in this regard.

Comment: @estus I don't want to write full article about this with extensive tests. You're asking me to write a test case, clarify browser support, do an investigation how it behaves on mobile platform, tell a story why, explain basic browser logic, etc. Sorry, I don't have time and I don't have so detailed knowledge. But I know that it works. P.S. Also I don't want to spend my time on this. I'm here to help people and also searching to some interesting questions where I could help, no more, no less. It's for fun.

Comment: @estus Anyway thank you. It was interesting discussion

Comment: Thank you too. I didn't really ask you to spare your time on that, just was interested if you had specific reading or examples at hand that could shed some light on the subject. I hope this case to become clearer if the OP will be able to provide working example for the problem.

Comment: @estus The more specific cases... mmmm... I used this trick while implementing some custom heavy logic over [jsPlumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/) library (automatic best arrow placement with path search), and it was done that time specially for Firefox, Firefox rendered page content multiple times, in Chrome this approach prevented zero-to-two page updates during calculation cycle (but they were here),  in the IE improvement was negligible or no boost at all, but IE had other problems :-) forgive me my English, not it is a little bit better - https://youtu.be/cbN09nPT9hQ?t=1153